# Import chat contacts

Tags: chat, google-workspace, google-talk, jabber, xmpp

I have a Google Apps account which I used for Chat.

my jabber used to be name@domain1.com

I use a new Domain with Google apps primarily now. So I want to import from my chat contacts from domains1.com to newdomain.com

What is the easiest way to do this.